# RazorEngine Razor.Parse(...) throws exception about ServiceStack and Markdown?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, email, razor

I ran this simple example from the website and I get the error below when it calls Razor.Parse. How can I fix this???

http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Markdown' does not exist in the namespace 'ServiceStack' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check the default namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you've linked to http://razorengine.codeplex.com

The 'ServiceStack' error assumes you want to use the Markdown engine in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) in which case you should be referencing the **RazorEngine.dll** that comes with ServiceStack not the one in `razorengine.codeplex.com` if that's what is done here.

Comment: I don't want to use Markdown. I did a NuGet to get the RazorEngine package and it is referencing thos dll's. I am using ServiceStack for some other unrelated JSON stuff in other parts of my project. I just don't understand why it is trying to load it. I think its a reflection issue. I think maybe putting an assembly dependency section in app.config might fix it. But I am still open to other ideas

Comment: If you just want to use the JsonSerializer you should NuGet uninstall ServiceStack and only nuget install ServiceStack.Text instead.

Comment: You don't understand my question. The question is why is RazorEngine asking for servicestack markdown stuff?

Comment: I doubt that is what's happening. It sounds like you have the ServiceStack version of RazorEngine.dll referenced instead. Can you provide a list or show a screenshot of your projs references?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine one of two things has happened. Either in your configuration file, namespaces have been added within the `<razorEngine>` configuration section, or the `AddNamespace` method is being called somewhere to include namespace imports in the compiled template.

The net result, is that namespaces are added to the generated class file, but references are missing. RazorEngine will automatically reference any loaded assemblies in the `AppDomain`.

Comment: This was a pain in the butt for me, finally figured out that the assembly I was using in my view had to be in the app domain when I called .Parse()..